# How to reduce line spacing of the footnote

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

I want to reduce the line spacing of the footnotes to be less than single spacing.

I am using the following to start the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openbib]{article}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[flushmargin,multiple]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
```

What should I add to reduce the line spacing of the footnotes?

Comment: If you use the `singlespacing` option, there will be no additional leading, so where's the problem? Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: this seems a rather odd requirement.  is a smaller-than-usual font being used for the footnotes?  if so, the line spacing of the "original" font may be used, instead of that for the smaller font.  the line spacing in the output isn't set until a paragraph break occurs.  try ending your footnote with `\endgraf` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. For all the text I want to have single spacing between lines, however, for the footnotes I want each lines (when text in the footnotes is large enough to make more than one line or there are many footnotes in a page) to be  closer than the single space. It would be like adding for each footnote in the document something like this: \footnote{\begin{spacing}{0.5} The footnote \end{spacing}}

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to reduce the font size of the footnotes rather than jam them so close together that ascenders and descenders (almost?) overlap.  It is good to consider whether your readers will find it too difficult to read the footnotes that they might as well not be present.  Alternatively, there is the `savetrees` package, which allows for all kinds of clever space-saving techniques; look at the `leadingfraction` option (although this applies also to the main text).

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can do something, there isn't the need to do it. I cannot advice anybody to do the following. Please, please, don't. The word *ugly* alone cannot describe the result.

[image: texsxFootnotesLinespread]

```
\documentclass[12pt,openbib]{article}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[flushmargin,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\def\FN@baselinestretch{.6}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```